# `%between%` (data.table) gives me a odd result

Tags: r, data.table, between

I would like to subset a data.table by specific date range, and I tried both between and inrange functions. I assume that %between% would give me the results. However, between produces an odd one.
Here is the sample data - subset the sample data by two periods (2014-05-06 ~ 2014-05-14 and 2015-05-06 ~ 2015-05-14).

```
# Create a sample dataset    
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(Date = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2014-01-01"),
                                 to = as.Date("2015-12-31"),
                                 by = 1),
                 Value = sample(365 * 2))

# Define the lower and upper ranges for the subsetting periods
lower = c(as.Date("2014-05-06"), as.Date("2015-05-06"))
upper = c(as.Date("2014-05-14"), as.Date("2015-05-14"))

# Try between function
DT[Date %between% list(lower, upper)]
# Some odd result
         Date Value
1: 2014-05-07   309
2: 2014-05-09   138
3: 2014-05-11   698
4: 2014-05-13    22
5: 2015-05-07   558
6: 2015-05-09   417
7: 2015-05-11   109
8: 2015-05-13   691

# Then try inrange function
DT[Date %inrange% list(lower, upper)]
# The results look good
          Date Value
 1: 2014-05-06   275
 2: 2014-05-07   309
 3: 2014-05-08   126
 4: 2014-05-09   138
 5: 2014-05-10   359
 6: 2014-05-11   698
 7: 2014-05-12    47
 8: 2014-05-13    22
 9: 2014-05-14   384
10: 2015-05-06     6
11: 2015-05-07   558
12: 2015-05-08   266
13: 2015-05-09   417
14: 2015-05-10    95
15: 2015-05-11   109
16: 2015-05-12   367
17: 2015-05-13   691
18: 2015-05-14   349
```

The inrange function produces the table I am after. by reading the data.table manual, I still not very clear about how between function works, particularly when lower and upper are provided outside DT as vectors. Could anyone give me some clue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Under Details section in `?between`,

> From v1.9.8+, `between` is vectorised. lower and upper are recycled to `length(x)` if necessary.

Hence, in `DT[Date %between% list(lower, upper)]`, it is more like

```
DT[Date %between% list(rep(lower, DT[,.N/length(lower)]), rep(upper, DT[,.N/length(upper)]))]
```

Whereas your understanding for `inrange` is still correct, i.e.

> `inrange` checks whether each value in x is in between any of the intervals provided in lower,upper.

Comment: Thank you so much, chinsoon12! It is clear to me now. When outside vectors are used for between function, between makes them the same length by recycling the elements in the vectors (if their lengths < DT[, .N]) to the same length of each column in the data.table, and then do the checking row by row.